# How to show that $AA^*+B^*B$ is invertible if $U\stackrel{A}\to V\stackrel{B}\to W$ is exact?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, exact-sequence

Let $U, V,$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces with inner products. If $A: U \rightarrow V$ and $B: V \rightarrow W$ are linear maps with adjoints $A^{*}$ and $B^{*},$ define the linear map $C: V \rightarrow V$ by
$$
C=A A^{*}+B^{*} B
$$
If $U \stackrel{A}{\longrightarrow} V \stackrel{B}{\longrightarrow}  W$ is exact , then my question is how to show $C: V \rightarrow V$ is invertible?

Here is my thought. We obviously have $W \stackrel{B^*}{\longrightarrow} V \stackrel{A^*}{\longrightarrow}  U$ is exact. Then $V=\text{Im}(B^*)\oplus \text{Im}(A)=\text{Ker}(A^*)\oplus\text{Ker}(B)$ thanks to it. Hence,

$C(V)=AA^*(\text{Ker}(B))+B^*B(\text{Ker}(A^*))=AA^*(\text{Im}(A))+B^*B(\text{Im}(B^*)),$ but what should I do next? I still wonder how to solve this problem by the matrix method.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, there is a decomposition $V=E\oplus F$ where $E=\ker(B)=\operatorname{im}(A)$ and $F=\ker(A^*)=\operatorname{im}(B^*)$.  Note that $AA^*$ vanishes on $F$ and maps $E$ to itself.  Moreover, $\ker(AA^*)=\ker(A^*)=F$ (if $AA^*v=0$ then $0=\langle AA^*v,v\rangle=\langle A^*v,A^*v\rangle$ so $A^*v=0$), so $AA^*$ is injective when restricted to $E$.  This means that the restriction of $AA^*$ to a map $E\to E$ is invertible.  Similarly, $B^*B$ vanishes on $E$ and restricts to an invertible map $F\to F$.

So, writing $C$ as a block matrix with respect to the decomposition $V=E\oplus F$, it is $\begin{pmatrix} AA^* & 0 \\ 0 & B^*B\end{pmatrix}$ where both diagonal entries are invertible (as maps $E\to E$ and $F\to F$).  Thus $C$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

I excountered a similar linear algebra problem:

> (i) Let $α: U → V$ be a linear map, show that $\operatorname{im}α∩\kerα^*=\{0\}$
>
> (ii) Let $α: U → V$ and $β: V → W$ be linear maps such that $\operatorname{im}α=\kerβ$. Let$$
> γ:=α α^*+β^* β
> $$
> Prove that $γ : V → V$ is invertible.

(i) is easy. The below is a solution to (ii)

To show $\gamma: V \rightarrow V$ is invertible, it is enough by the Rank-Nullity Theorem to show that ker $\gamma=\{0\}$.

Suppose that $\gamma(x)=0$.

Then $\alpha \alpha^*(x)=-\beta^* \beta(x) \in\operatorname{im} \alpha$.

Since $\operatorname{im} \alpha=\operatorname{ker} \beta$, we deduce $\beta \beta^* \beta(x)=0$.

Hence $\beta^* \beta(x) \in \operatorname{im} \beta^* \cap \operatorname{ker} \beta=\operatorname{im} \beta^* \cap\operatorname{ker}\left(\beta^*\right)^*=\{0\}$ by (i) applied to $\beta^*$, so $\beta^* \beta(x)=0$.

Hence $\beta(x) \in \operatorname{im} \beta \cap \operatorname{ker} \beta^*=\{0\}$ again by (i) applied to $\beta$, so $\boxed{\beta(x)=0}$.

Hence $\alpha \alpha^*(x)=-\beta^* \beta(x)=0$, so $\alpha^*(x) \in$ $\operatorname{im} \alpha^* \cap \operatorname{ker} \alpha=\operatorname{im} \alpha^* \cap \operatorname{ker}\left(\alpha^*\right)^*=\{0\}$, again by (i) applied to $\alpha^*$. Hence $\boxed{\alpha^*(x)=0}$.

Since $x \in \operatorname{ker} \beta=\operatorname{Im} \alpha$ we can write $x=\alpha(y)$ for some $y \in U$.

Then $\alpha^* \alpha(y)=\alpha^*(x)=0$, so $\alpha(y) \in \operatorname{Im} \alpha \cap\ker \alpha^*=\{0\}$ by (i). Hence $x=\alpha(y)=0$.